# Bind dropdownlist in gridview in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, html.dropdownlistfor

**html code:**

```
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Literal ID="faculty" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("facultyname")%>'>
            </asp:Literal>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="fact" runat="server">
            </asp:DropDownList>
```

**code bihind:**

```
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)

        {
            DropDownList dropdown = GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("fact") as DropDownList;
            facultyDal c = new facultyDal();
            dropdown.DataSource = c.show();
            dropdown.DataBind();
            dropdown.DataTextField = "facultyname";
            dropdown.DataValueField = "facultyid";

        }
```

**Exception:**

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

When i bind to dropdown with datasource the above exception occur please help....

Comment: when object reference exception is received then it tells us something is not initialized
first debug and check if dropdown is not null
(DropDownList dropdown = GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("fact") as DropDownList;)
second check in debug if (c.show) is not null

Answer (score 1):

Try like this using RowDataBound.

For Binding in editmode

```
protected void RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && gvCustomers.EditIndex == e.Row.RowIndex)
    {
        DropDownList ddlfaculties = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("fact");
        string query = "select distinct facultyname from your-Table-Name";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
        ddlfaculties .DataSource = GetData(cmd);
        ddlfaculties .DataTextField = "facultyname";
        ddlfaculties .DataValueField = "facultyid";
        ddlfaculties .DataBind();
        ddlfaculties .Items.FindByValue((e.Row.FindControl("faculty") as Literal).Text).Selected = true;
    }
}
```

For uddating the selected value from dropdown list.

```
protected void RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && gvCustomers.EditIndex == e.Row.RowIndex)
    {
        DropDownList ddlfaculties = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("fact");
        string query = "select distinct facultyname from Your-Table-Name";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
        ddlfaculties .DataSource = GetData(cmd);
        ddlfaculties .DataTextField = "facultyname";
        ddlfaculties .DataValueField = "facultyid";
        ddlfaculties .DataBind();
        ddlfaculties .Items.FindByValue((e.Row.FindControl("faculty") as Literal).Text).Selected = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your code to following

**GridView1.EditIndex**

```
DropDownList dropdown = GridView1.Rows[GridView1.EditIndex].FindControl("fact") as DropDownList;
```

Answer (score 0):

using grid view rowdatabound evet we can bind the data to web control in grid view

[get row and find the control using edit index then bind data](http://forums.asp.net/p/1857575/5206062.aspx/1?Bind%20data%20to%20dropdown%20in%20gridview%20)

Answer (score 0):

The error coming because of you trying to bind data to dropdown list before edit mode enable.

```
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    gridbind();//fetch data from database and bind to grid
    DropDownList dropdown = GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("fact") as DropDownList;
    facultyDal c = new facultyDal();
    dropdown.DataSource = c.show();
    dropdown.DataBind();
    dropdown.DataTextField = "facultyname";
    dropdown.DataValueField = "facultyid";
}
```